# Set property in forEach loop

Tags: ember.js

I have an array of object where I need to set a property to true or false on each one. How do you set a property on an array using @set? Also, if done on an array like this, will the new values (true/false) carry over into the template? Thanks in advance for the help. Here is my code:

```
  formTypesWithUsed: Ember.computed 'formTypes.[]', ->
    @get('formTypes').forEach (formType)->
      @set 'formType.formTypeUsed', true

formTypes:
  [
    { name: 'some form 1', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 2', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 3', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 4', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 5', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 6', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 7', formTypeUsed: false }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the following. Thanks to Duncan for all the help:

```
formTypes: Em.A [
    { name: 'some form 1', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 2', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 3', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 4', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 5', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 6', formTypeUsed: false }
    { name: 'some form 7', formTypeUsed: false }
  ]

formTypesWithCount: Em.computed '@formTypes', ->

  formTypes = @get('formTypes').map (formType)->
    Em.Object.create().setProperties(formType)

  formTypes.map (formType)->
    formType.set 'formTypeUsed', true
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as an FYI it's easier and more effecient to use `setEach` if you are setting a property across an entire collection.

```
@get('formTypes').setEach 'formTypeUsed', true
```

Answer (score 1):

In JS (I tried to use a coffee convertor but it didn't look correct):

```
formTypesWithUsed: function() {
  return this.get('formTypes').forEach(function(formType) {
    formType.set('formTypeUsed', true);
  });
}.property('formTypes.[]'),
```

So long as you used `{{#each formTypesWithUsed}}` in your template, everything is bound and the new values will carry over into the template. If you're looking to change the true/false values on the actual `formTypes` property and use `{{#each}}` or `{{#each controller}}`, you should use an observer instead of a computed property but the function will remain the same minus the `return`.

Any time you use `set()`, Handlebars will show the new value automatically.

Comment: Hey Duncan! I am such a noob. Sometimes with coffeescript I forget which 'this' I'm referring to. For some reason I'm still getting 'undefined is not a function' though.

Comment: Is `formTypes` definitely an `Ember.Array`?

Comment: It's literally declared just like it is above. I think my main problem is that I'm not using the formTypes array the correct 'Ember' way like  you said. How do I declare that array in the right way so that Ember knows how to manipulate it?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see that. Try `formTypes: Em.A([ //... objects here ])`.

Comment: Now there is no error but nothing shows up in the list. If I change it back to the other, they show up but it throws the error.

Comment: Sorry I think it may be a coffescript thing. One minute.

Comment: Ok I think the array is good to go now but I still get the undefined type error when I try set anything on formType.

Comment: If you make an [emberjs.jsbin.com](http://emberjs.jsbin.com) I probably have a better chance of figuring out what's going wrong here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57244/discussion-between-duncan-walker-and-sturoid).